# NM cable from wall box to dishwaster

Tags: electrical, dishwasher, junction-box, garbage-disposal

I need to connect my dishwasher to an electrical box in the wall under the sink but it is recessed so the cable must come out through the front plate and not side knockouts. Out of the same box will also be coming a similar cable but for the garbage disposal. The wall box is a regular metal handy box, 2.5x4 or something like that.

Is it okay to have two 14/2 NM cables coming out of the front plate of an electrical box and be basically exposed inside an enclosure (sink cabinet) on its way to the appliance? Should I get a coverplate that has two knockouts through which I would fit two NM cables fitted with clamp connectors?

Comment: If someone roughly shoved a trash can or baking dish under there, could they potentially hit the NM cable?

Comment: I take it the dishwasher has a box on it for terminating a cable into? What make/model is it?

Comment: The dishwasher is a direct wire in connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not run NM sheathed cable through a cabinet that has doors which open to allow storage.

You should be installing grounded receptacles and using appliance connector cords.

[image]

Comment: The cord gets messed up.  And our AHJ does not want cords going through any wall. Even cabinet wall .

Comment: Is there a reason these appliance connector cords come at a 90deg angle? It makes sharing of an outlet with another plug more difficult or impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a box extension for device box, to four inch deep square box. Only place i got them was at big box store. Add outlet there for pig . Then run metallic licquatite to dishwasher outlet, add a cord .Have your disconnect . are these the only loads on this breaker? Watch out may have to add new feeds.